# Visual Studio Team services - load testing - JMeter - path to supporting files

Tags: jmeter, azure-devops, load-testing

I'd like to use Visual Studio Team Services to run load testing plan written in JMeter in cloud. In my test I have to upload file.
I guess I should attach this file to 'Supporting files' field, but I have no idea what is the path to this file. There are error message:

`HttpError Non HTTP response code: java.io.FileNotFoundException Agent000 | Thread Group | Upload | Non HTTP response message: test.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)`

I've tried some paths which I found in log, eg: `E:\approot\JMeterLoadTest\`, but there are error anyway.

What is the path to file added to 'Supporting files'? Has anybody had similiar problem?

Comment: Are you using some sampler like BeanShell  to read the xml file in your tests?

Comment: No. `test.xml` is example file to upload, I dont read this file, just send it by Http put method. In JMeter I use Http request sampler, on Files Upload tab I write the path to file in my local drive. And I need to know the path to file, when test is executing in cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define "User Defined Variables" and use BeanShell.

```
  <Arguments guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
    <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
      <elementProp name="testURL" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">testURL</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">www.datafilehost.com</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="testFile" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">testFile</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">upload.txt</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
      <elementProp name="scriptPath" elementType="Argument">
        <stringProp name="Argument.name">scriptPath</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.value">${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();)}${__BeanShell(File.separator,)}</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
      </elementProp>
    </collectionProp>
  </Arguments>
```

and than you can load file from your base dir:

```
      <elementProp name="HTTPsampler.Files" elementType="HTTPFileArgs">
        <collectionProp name="HTTPFileArgs.files">
          <elementProp name="${scriptPath}${testFile}" elementType="HTTPFileArg">
            <stringProp name="File.path">${scriptPath}${testFile}</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="File.paramname">upfile</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="File.mimetype">text/plain</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </elementProp>
```

Full sample:
https://github.com/aliesbelik/jmx/blob/master/so/2015-04-15_file-upload-download.jmx